# Pandas Group By And Get Dummies

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, dummy-variable

I want to make get dummy variables per unique value. Idea is to turn the data frame into a multi-label target. How can I do it?

**Data:**

```
           ID                      L2
           A                 Firewall
           A                 Security
           B           Communications
           C                 Business
           C                 Switches
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ID   Firewall  Security  Communications  Business   Switches
 A      1          1             0              0         0
 B      0          0             1              0         0
 C      0          0             0              1         1
```

I have tried `pd.pivot_table` but it requires a column to aggregate on. I have also tried answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666441/how-to-group-by-and-dummies-in-pandas) but it sums the values rather than just turning into binary dummy columns. I would much appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us `set_index` then `get_dummies`, since we have multiple duplicate in each ID ,we need to `sum` with `level = 0`

```
s = df.set_index('ID')['L2'].str.get_dummies().max(level=0).reset_index()
Out[175]: 
  ID  Business  Communications  Firewall  Security  Switches
0  A         0               0         1         1         0
1  B         0               1         0         0         0
2  C         1               0         0         0         1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a bigger data frame and using `sum` is actually `summing` the values so I'm not getting just binary columns.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal use `max` instead of `sum`

Comment: There, it is!! Thanks a lot. Also, thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why using the max function?

Comment: @Utopia multiple same column with 0 and 1 we only want return 1 any of them is 1 , that is why use max

Answer (score 8):

`crosstab`, then convert to boolean:

```
pd.crosstab(df['ID'],df['L2']).astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
L2  Business  Communications  Firewall  Security  Switches
ID                                                        
A      False           False      True      True     False
B      False            True     False     False     False
C       True           False     False     False      True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df2 = df1.groupby(['ID'])['L2'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
df3 = df2["L2"].str.get_dummies(",")
df = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis = 1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  ID                 L2  Business  Communications  Firewall  Security  Switches
0  A  Firewall,Security         0               0         1         1         0
1  B     Communications         0               1         0         0         0
2  C  Business,Switches         1               0         0         0         1
```

**Alternative Option:**

```
df = df.groupby(['ID'])['L2'].apply(','.join).str.get_dummies(",").reset_index()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pivot_table` if you change the `aggfunc=any`.

```
print(df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='L2', 
                     aggfunc=any, fill_value=False)\
        .astype(int))
L2  Business  Communications  Firewall  Security  Switches
ID                                                        
A          0               0         1         1         0
B          0               1         0         0         0
C          1               0         0         0         1
```

and maybe `reset_index` at the end to put the ID as column